# Coupon Plugin the cart is shown as empty

Tags: magento2, cart, plugin, coupon

I want to create a plugin to hook into the CouponManagement System. I hook into beforeSet and it triggers but the cart is shown as empty, This is my code:

```
  protected $_quote;
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
  ){
    $this->_quote = $quoteFactory;
  }

  public function beforeSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode){
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $this->logger = $objectManager->create('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    $this->logger->debug('test before set');

    $cart = $this->_quote->create()->get($cartId);
    $this->logger->debug($cart);
  }
```

Can someone help me to get the actual cart?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
```

with

```
\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
```

and then

```
$cart = $this->_quote->create()->get($cartId);
```

change to

```
$cart = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
```

### Code Sample:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
 */
private $quoteRepository;
private $logger;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface    $logger
) {

    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

public function beforeSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode) {

    $this->logger->debug('test before set');

    $cart = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if (!$cart->getItemsCount()) {
        //throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
         $this->logger->debug(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
    }
    $this->logger->debug($cart->debug());
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. But why I only become it with $cart->debug()? $cart only gives empty response too. And how can i get the items inside?

Comment: have you getting the error message  at `Cart doesn\'t contain products` at log?

Comment: use ` $this->logger->debug($cart->getId());`   instread of ` $this->logger->debug($cart->debug());`

Comment: no the error message is not shown. getId() gives me the right id.